How to install an NVIDIA GTX 760 Driver for Fedora
I want to install a GPU Driver for my HP Z440 Workstation.
I'm on Fedora 40 Worksation Edition
The screen has low resolution and the OS thinks that my screen is bigger so it writes image data to nothing (the screen is "cropped").
I tried the akmod-nvidia driver/package, nothing is solved, but the cursor while loading forgets to delete the cursor image when moving the cursor (there are multiple cursors that are deleted by the real cursor when moving over them), and it's random, meaning that it's not continuously forgetting to delete the cursor from the current rendering and it duplicates the cursor instead of moving it.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148
